# Not Getting Proper location of CALayer iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I am working CALayer in iOS added a sublayers in myView and trying to get touch event through touches began but i am getting touch event not at the location where i have drawn the layer, plz help me in correcting it if smthing is wrong.

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

magicButton_ = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
magicButton_.frame = CGRectMake(10., 10., 300., 44.);
[magicButton_ setTitle:@"Invoke Magic!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[magicButton_ addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleMoney:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myView addSubview:magicButton_];

simpleLayer_ = [[CALayer alloc]init];


simpleLayer_.bounds = CGRectMake(0., 0., 150., 20.);
simpleLayer_.position = CGPointMake((myView.center.x),(myView.center.y));
simpleLayer_.name = @"redlayer";
simpleLayer_.delegate = self;
simpleLayer_.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
[myView.layer addSublayer:simpleLayer_];
self.view = myView;

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CALayer *hitLayer = [self.view.layer hitTest:[self.view convertPoint:location             fromView:nil]];

    NSLog(@"Location %f  %f",location.x,location.y);
    [self displayInfo:hitLayer.name];
}


-(void)displayInfo:(NSString *)nameOfLayer
{
   NSLog(@"%@",nameOfLayer);
}

2013-10-14 13:13:37.374 MyLayerProj[1750:11303] (null)
2013-10-14 13:13:38.468 MyLayerProj[1750:11303] Location 87.000000  269.000000
2013-10-14 13:13:38.469 MyLayerProj[1750:11303] (null)
2013-10-14 13:13:39.239 MyLayerProj[1750:11303] Location 112.000000  278.000000
2013-10-14 13:13:39.240 MyLayerProj[1750:11303] redlayer
2013-10-14 13:13:40.479 MyLayerProj[1750:11303] Location 119.000000  278.000000
```

I have also included the logs which i am getting while running the code.

Comment: It's been a long time since I saw someone use a CGLayer. I was hoping for some fun, old-school Core Graphics hackery but unfortunately you were talking about CALayer (Core Animation) :(

Answer (score 1):

The `[self.view convertPoint:location fromView:nil]` in your call to `-[CALayer hitTest]` means "convert `location` from the co-ordinate space of the window to the co-ordinate space of `self.view`".

However, `location` is already in the co-ordinate space of the view, because you obtained it from passing `self.view` to `-[UITouch locationInView:]`.

Comment: So what will be the exact way to get the location in my case.

Comment: Just don't use the extra `-[UIView convertPoint:fromView:]`, i.e. just have `CALayer *hitLayer = [self.view.layer hitTest:location];`

Comment: I think -hitTest: expects coordinates in the parent layer's coordinate space.

Comment: now i am trying this way        CALayer *hitLayer = [self.view.layer hitTest:location];